# apache shutdown unexpedly and i can not fix it anyhow?

Tags: apache, xampp

xampp giving this error when i am trying to start apache.

```
Status change detected: running
Status change detected: stopped
Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
If you need more help, copy and post this
entire log window on the forums
```

I have taken many step to solve this problem but it doesn't solve.
I changed the port on httdp.conf and httdp-ssl.conf file but it's not solve

please help me...

Answer (score 0):

If you have Skype open I recommend you close it because sometimes it generates conflicts.